# Where do i put the build.groovy file in my grails project?

Tags: grails, gradle, ggts

i have Searched few website online, they say to put in root folder, but i cant find any root folder in my project.
i am using GGTS for my project and want to have a gradle build.

Comment: put in Configuration Folder

Comment: after that is just have to run the application simply? or do i have to do other tasks(if any please tell)?

Comment: Put There and run

Comment: how do we know that its a gradle build after running the app?

Comment: Actually i am new to grails and gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Root folder is not a folder named "root". It's a main folder which
>   your project is in.

Named the same as your project. You open up that folder and put the `build.groovy` file right in there. the path would be `.../your_project_name/build.groovy` 
You can actually use [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html) tutorial to see detailed description about gradle build in GGTS.